# Django raw query total count

Tags: python, django

I have a raw query, for example:

```
# Table posts = 420 rows
>>> cursor = connection.cursor()
>>> posts = Post.objects.raw('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS posts.* FROM posts LIMIT 1,10')
>>> found_rows = cursor.execute("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()")
>>> print found_rows()
1
```

I want to know how to get the total number of rows is for paging.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Post.objects.raw()` does not execute the query — it only returns a `RawQuerySet` instance. The actual query will only be executed once you try to iterate over that `RawQuerySet` (e.g. by calling `next(iter(posts))` in your code).

Since you're limiting your query to only 10 results, you might just pull all instances in a list:

```
posts = list(Post.objects.raw('SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS posts.* FROM posts LIMIT 1,10'))
```

This will make sure that your query has been executed for your next `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` to return the actual count.